# Iterate through each rows in pandas dataframe and get value from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 pandas dataframe, df, df_a, df_b as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'table': ["a", "a", "b"], 'seq': ["xx", "xy", "z"]})
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={'a_id': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ["fg", "rt", "zh"]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={'b_id': [4, 5, 6], 'col1': ["", "gh", "k"]})
```

I want to create a new dataframe with below condition
for row in df,

if seq is xx, get a_id from df_a and have the seq value added for those a_ids (xx)

if seq is xy, get a_id from df_a and have the seq value added for those a_ids (xy)

if seq is z, get b_id from df_b and have the seq value added for those b_ids (z)

Expected output:

```
   a_id seq b_id
0   1.0 xx  NaN
1   2.0 xx  NaN
2   3.0 xx  NaN
0   1.0 xy  NaN
1   2.0 xy  NaN
2   3.0 xy  NaN
0   NaN z   4.0
1   NaN z   5.0
2   NaN z   6.0
```

Here is my code:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)) :
    if df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'xx':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_a[['a_id']])
        df_final['seq'] = df.loc[i, "seq"]
    elif df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'xy':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_a[['a_id']])
        df_final['seq'] = df.loc[i, "seq"]
    elif df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'z':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_b[['b_id']])
        df_final['seq'] = df.loc[i, "seq"]
```

which returns z for all rows as below

```
   a_id seq b_id
0   1.0 z   NaN
1   2.0 z   NaN
2   3.0 z   NaN
0   1.0 z   NaN
1   2.0 z   NaN
2   3.0 z   NaN
0   NaN z   4.0
1   NaN z   5.0
2   NaN z   6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of your "table" column, you can combine [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (
 df.merge(pd.concat({'a': df_a, 'b': df_b}, names=['table']),
          on='table', how='left')
   #.drop(columns=['table', 'seq']) # optional cleanup
)
```

*NB. if "table" doesn't exist, create it with a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html): `df['table'] = df['seq'].map({'xx': 'a', 'xy': 'a', z': 'b'})`.*

Output:

```
  table seq  a_id col1  b_id
0     a  xx   1.0   fg   NaN
1     a  xx   2.0   rt   NaN
2     a  xx   3.0   zh   NaN
3     a  xy   1.0   fg   NaN
4     a  xy   2.0   rt   NaN
5     a  xy   3.0   zh   NaN
6     b   z   NaN        4.0
7     b   z   NaN   gh   5.0
8     b   z   NaN    k   6.0
```

Comment: what I was going for, 2 mins too late. You don't really need to reset index for concat though, I think `merge` works on index name.

Comment: Sorry @Quang ! (if it makes you feel better, this was the other way around yesterday, you scooped me on a few answers, which I happily upvoted :p)

Answer (score 1):

Just fix your code

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)) :
    if df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'xx':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_a[['a_id']])
        df_final['seq'] = df.loc[i, "seq"]
    elif df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'xy':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_a[['a_id']])
        df_final['seq'].fillna(df.loc[i, "seq"],inplace=True)
    elif df.loc[i, "seq"] == 'z':
        df_final = df_final.append(df_b[['b_id']])
        df_final['seq'].fillna(df.loc[i, "seq"],inplace=True)
        
df_final
Out[14]: 
   a_id seq  b_id
0   1.0  xx   NaN
1   2.0  xx   NaN
2   3.0  xx   NaN
0   1.0  xy   NaN
1   2.0  xy   NaN
2   3.0  xy   NaN
0   NaN   z   4.0
1   NaN   z   5.0
2   NaN   z   6.0
```

Comment: Good to see you around dear sir.

Comment: @cs95 Happy to see you again my friend